# How to Use HierarchyId in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

We are use ef core for multi db type, facing some issue again the hierarchyId,
HierarchyId data type is not a available in Ef Core.
what is a way to manage hiearacharId ?

Answer (score 0):

The community-driven [EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId) project can help.

```sh
dotnet add package EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId
```

```cs
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.UseHierarchyId());
```

```cs
var thirdGeneration = from p in dbContext.Patriarchs
                      where p.Id.GetLevel() == 2
                      select p;
```